# MDCTextInputControllerOutlined does not align text

Tags: ios, swift, mdc-components

[image]

I am trying to use MDCTextField https://material.io/develop/ios/components/textfields/ . I need it to be the same as an example. But I always get the result as in the picture. I've already tried

```
controller.textInsets(UIEdgeInsets(top: 16, left: 16, bottom: 16, right: 16))
```

But it does not work. I am using storyboard. Here is my code.

```
@IBOutlet weak var uiAddHost: MDCTextField!

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let controller = MDCTextInputControllerOutlined(textInput: uiAddHost)
    controller.activeColor = Colors.graphRed
    controller.disabledColor = Colors.site_green
    controller.textInsets(UIEdgeInsets(top: 16, left: 16, bottom: 16, right: 16))
}
```

Comment: Could you find any solution?

Comment: @RezaDehnavi I got that material library for iOS is complete bs. So I am just using an equivalent library for TextField.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
@IBOutlet weak var uiAddHost: MDCTextField!
var controller: MDCTextInputControllerOutlined?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    controller = MDCTextInputControllerOutlined(textInput: uiAddHost)
    controller.activeColor = Colors.graphRed
    controller.disabledColor = Colors.site_green
    controller.textInsets(UIEdgeInsets(top: 16, left: 16, bottom: 16, right: 16))
}
```

I had the same problem.
I solved it with the code above, but I don't know why this works.